# MongoDB Aggregation to get events in timespan, plus the previous event

Tags: mongodb

I have timeseries data as events coming in at random times. They are not ongoing metrics, but rather events. "This device went online." "This device went offline."

I need to report on the number of *actual* transitions within a time range. Because there are occasionally same-state events, for example two "went online" events in a row, I need to "seed" the data with the state previous to the time range. If I have events in my time range, I need to compare them to the state before the time range in order to determine if something actually changed.

I already have aggregation stages that remove same-state events.

Is there a way to add "the latest, previous event" to the data in the pipeline without writing two queries? A $facet stage totally ruins performance.

For "previous", I'm currently trying something like this in a separate query, but it's very slow on the millions of records:

```
// Get the latest event before a given date
db.devicemetrics.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      'device.someMetadata': '70b28808-da2b-4623-ad83-6cba3b20b774',
      time: {
        $lt: ISODate('2023-01-18T07:00:00.000Z'),
      },
      someValue: { $ne: null },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$device._id',
      lastEvent: { $last: '$$ROOT' },
    },
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$lastEvent' },
  }
]);
```

Comment: Can you show us the sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something akin to LAG window function in SQL. Mongo has [$setWindowFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) for this, combined with [$shift](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/shift/#mongodb-group-grp.-shift) Order operator.

Not sure about fields in your collection, but this should give you an idea.

```
{
   $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$device._id", //1. partition the data based on $device._id
      sortBy: { time: 1 },        //2. within each partition, sort based on $time
      output: {
         "shiftedEvent": {        //3. add a new field shiftedEvent to each document
            $shift: {
               output: "$event",  //4. whose value is previous $event
               by: -1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then, you can compare the event and shiftedEvent fields.

Comment: Thank you bu I think I was unclear:  I need to get a range of events in a timespan, but also the latest event previous to the timespan. This gets me part of the way there but the previous is attached to the next and I can't put the time restraints match stage until after this so the query time jumps up 4X (30 seconds+) and I still have the problem of getting the shiftedEvent out to the start of the documents so I can continue my pipeline.

Comment: Can you show sample documents and expected output.